# Xdebug doesn't work since upgrading to Mac os Sierra

Tags: php, xdebug, macos-sierra

Since I upgraded to mac os Sierra, the xdebug extension doesn't work.

- When I'm doing php -v, the xdebug is shown as installed.
- When i'm going to the extension library ( /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226 ), the xdebug.so file is there.
- When I'm opening the phpinfo(), the xdebug doesn't being shown.

i'm using php v5.6.28 and xdebug that is installed is v2.3.3 and trying to run this on phpstrom.

Before the upgrade everything worked fine.

Comment: Care to share your `xdebug` configuration in PHPStorm also? Also maybe tag this with the `phpstorm` tag for wider range.

Comment: Check that the php.ini you are using in your CLI is the same as the one you are using for your local server. If it isn't ensure your local Apache's php.ini file has xDebug enabled

Comment: *"When I'm opening the phpinfo(), the xdebug doesn't being shown."* How do you do that? I mean -- in terminal or via browser?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, in my case, it was because install xdebug using `brew`, and libraries do not have the right path. So just need to copy `xdebug.so` in path referenced in `php.ini`

```
cp /usr/local/Cellar/php56-xdebug/2.5.4/xdebug.so /usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/
```